# What is this P4 correspond to in proposition as types?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I was reading "Proofs and Types", so there came across that any proposition can be converted to lambda form. So was trying out with Hilbert system's axioms

P1. $A \rightarrow A $

P2. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$

P3. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$

P4. $ (A \rightarrow B ) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow \lnot B) \rightarrow \lnot A) $

I could get that P1 is $I$ combinator and P2 is $K$ and P3 is $S$. P1 is redundant since $I = SK$. But i couldnt figure out how to turn P4 into $\lambda$ form. Even though i get how $\lnot A = A \rightarrow \bot$ .

Also if there is no equivalent of P4 in Combinatory logic then, basically i cannot express negative stuff in Combinatory logic at all?

Comment: Two alternatives to P4 : *(i)* $\lnot \lnot A \to A$, expressed with $¬A =A→⊥$; *(ii) [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law) : $((A \to B) \to A) \to A$

Comment: But is there a lambda form for Pierce's law? I read its the type of continuations, i cant think of how i can write a lambda expression with that as type. But i can do that for others